# Run function based on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to run a function if a cell value is "Smartphone".  I have tried a few ways of writing this but it keeps failing and can not figure out the right way to type it.

```
function ifTest(event){
if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B11").getValue() = "Smartphone"){ // mobile phone check
    emailMobileRequired(); // Launches the script
  }
}
```

Comment: function ifTest(event){
if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B11").getValue() == "Smartphone"){ // mobile phone check
    emailMobileRequired(); // Launches the script
  }
} This should work, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use two equal signs instead of one to compare two values and test for equality. (read more: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

In javascript one equal sign is an assignment operator. The expression result on the right is assigned to the variable on the left. (read more: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)